# android activity without parent activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Being new to Android I am not getting the coding conventions for android.
My project has one activity which is MainActivity.

Now can we create another activity without having MainActivity as parent activity?
And per application, there should be only one Main Activity (Only one parent activity for all other activity) or can there be more than one Main Activities (Parent Activities)?

Comment: You are confused... just write simply what you actually want to do..

Comment: Yes I am....I want to create more than one parent activity...like in eclipse while crating an activity I will leave "Hierarchical Parent" blank. So is it advisable...I mean I don't know what should be the good coding practice for android...

Comment: parent activity or parent View?

Comment: a View is associated with an Activity..right.? Or I am getting it wrong?

Comment: yes you are right!! but wat u want to actually do?

do you want to make an activity with multiple view groups or multiple activities for multiple Views??

Comment: multiple activities for multiple Views

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16364/discussion-between-hemu-and-aditya-nikhade)

Answer (score 2):

Check this [`Application Fundamentals`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)